# Compare datatable and SQL table

Tags: c#, clr

So I googled and searched... is there a simple way to compare the table structure of a SQL table to a CLR datatable?

Here is the issue: we have an API that returns JSON which is constantly evolving. When the return array contains new objects we would like to notify the caller that more data is available.

We can get the SQL schema pretty easy with a query:

```
select COLUMN_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'ApiWork'
```

But how can we compare the column/ordinal to the DataTable holding the JSON array?
A typical return array would look like this:

```
 {"Index_0":"930477","Index_1":"test789","ArrayID":"1","Result":"OK","Order_ID":"930477","Model_Number":"FGHB2868TF","Ship_Date":"05/30/2018","Allocated":0,"Backordered":1,"Amount":0}
```

And we could build a datatable with a json deserializer or with a loop:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlPipe pipe = SqlContext.Pipe;
        String d = "";
        String col = "";
        int l = 0;
        int l2 = 0;
        int s = 0;
        int s2 = 0;
        o = "{\"Index_0\":\"930477\",\"Index_1\":\"test789\",\"ArrayID\":\"1\",\"Result\":\"OK\",\"DMI_Order_ID\":\"930477\",\"Model_Number\":\"FGHB2868TF\",\"Ship_Date\":\"05/30/2018\",\"Allocated\":0,\"Backordered\":1,\"Amount\":0}";
        int c = o.Length;
        while (c > 0)
        {
            col = o.Substring(0, o.IndexOf(":")).Replace("\"", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
            l = o.IndexOf(":");
            l = l + 1;
            s = o.Length - l;
            o = o.Substring(l,s); // here we have removed the name portion
            l2 = o.IndexOf(",");
            l2 = l2 + 1;
            s2 = o.Length - l2;
            o = o.Substring(l2, s2); // here we have removed the value of the previous name

            c = o.Length;
            if (o.IndexOf(":") == -1 && o.IndexOf(",") == -1)
            {
                c = 0;
            }
        }
```

I suppose looping like this would allow control of the ordinal as well if that were necessary but as I mentioned in one of my comments this is not completely necessary.

Comment: One question would bey does the ordinal/order of the data in the SQL table compared to your object matter?  Usually it does not (order being the column order not data)

Comment: @Brad - I suppose that doesn't really matter. the DataTable is used for bulk insert into the corresponding work table.

Comment: Just something to think of when trying to do your comparison.  Removing the need to keep the ordinal position will make it easier to do a comparison.

Comment: If you can provide some code examples of your objects and how you are populating them that could help.  Also do you need to compare the data types or just check for column names that are newly added?

Comment: No need to compare data types as we handle conversion in MSSQL. Everything comes across as nvarchar. A typical JSON row would be something like `{"Index_0":"930477","Index_1":"test789","ArrayID":"1","Result":"OK","Order_ID":"930477","Model_Number":"FGHB2868TF","Ship_Date":"05/30/2018","Allocated":0,"Backordered":1,"Amount":0}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this appears to do the job simply:

```
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select name from tempdb.sys.COLUMNS  Where object_id=OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#ApiWork')EXCEPT Select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'ApiWork'"))
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        pipe.Send("Something is different!");
                    }else{
                        pipe.Send("we're all good!");
                    }

                }
            }
```

These two queries can be checked to see if columns are different. As an aside

```
COLUMN_ID
```

and

```
ORDINAL_ID
```

can be added to the queries and then can be checked as well.